# Java String contain method and enum

Tags: java, enums

I have enum defined in class as

```
public enum EnumSample {
    SPACE,
    NASA,
    SPUTNIK;
}
```

In class Test, I have a method with following code snippet

```
if (str.contains(<>)) {
```

Is it possible to search all enum values in contain method of String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the `.values()` of the enum and apply `.contains()` for each of them.

For example:

```
for (EnumSample value : EnumSample.values()) {
    if (str.contains(value.name()) {
        //do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `value.name()`?

Comment: It's the name of the enum constant. Checkout the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()). :)

Comment: What's the `str` value?

Comment: kocko It is working perfectly, there were some issues with my code and thus I had few errors which was not due to  `value.name()` Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with `contains` is that it finds parts of words - for example, it would find "NASA" in "NASAL DECONGESTANTS". If you would like your comparison to be fast, and look for specific words, not parts of words, use regex search instead.

The regex for your example would look like this:

```
\b(SPACE|NASA|SPUTNIK)\b
```

You can construct and use it like this:

```
static Pattern allEnumVals;

static {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("\\b(");
    boolean first = true;
    for (EnumSample e : EnumSample.values()) {
        if (!first) {
            b.append("|");
        } else {
            first = false;
        }
        b.append(e.name());
    }
    b.append(")\\b");
    allEnumVals = Pattern.compile(b.toString());
}

static boolean check(String str) {
    return allEnumVals.matcher(str).find();
}
```